# Short story where an alien signal containing a DNA sequence leads to the end of life on Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, online-resources

I read this short story online some time in the past 10 years. Year and author unknown.

It starts on an alien planet where the only life is a red (?) moss or lichen. At some point a gigantic antenna sends out a signal, I think this happens as a result of the moss-lifeform somehow detecting radio waves from space.

The signal reaches Earth, and is interpreted as a DNA sequence.
The sequence becomes commonplace in experiments and teaching, and is eventually everywhere, harmlessly hiding away in most life on the planet.
Suddenly one day the sequence expresses itself by turning all life on Earth into the same red(?) moss or lichen, starting the cycle over.

Comment: I remember this one - will answer when I get to a place with steady Internet

Comment: Not really the end of life on earth, but a substantial modification.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis the story (which I just read) insinuates the end stage of the moss-virus is total extermination, since it destroys the ecosystem that keeps the moss running; its last energy is spent building the communication antenna, which only lasts for 2 years.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

John Barnes' [*Enrico Fermi and the Dead Cat*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?99655), published as far as I can tell only in his collection **Apostrophes and Apocalypses**

Brief mention of the story [here](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2018/03/malware_from_sp.html)

> The ultimately hideous version of this (**more or less an interstellar
> email trojan that eats everyone who reconstructs the organism encoded
> in its message alive from the inside out along with their biosphere,
> then mindlessly builds transmitters to retransmit the signal**) is found
> in John Barnes’s Enrico Fermi and the Dead Cat, reproduced
> in Apostrophes and Apocalypses. It is a few pages long and is probably
> the most disturbing thing in a book which should come with a
> DISTURBING: DO NOT READ on the cover in big red letters. (But then, it
> kind of does: the author’s name. He’s never written anything
> that isn’t suicidally depressing.)
>
> (It’s not actually shown as malware, but do you think massive
> transmitters are evolved? I don’t. This is someone’s weapon that got
> loose long ago. They were probably the first ones eaten.)

This [review](https://www-users.york.ac.uk/%7Ess44/books/pages/b/JohnBarnes.htm) of the collection has summaries of each story which will probably trigger other memories if you encountered the story there:

> - **Enrico Fermi and the Dead Cat**. 1998
>   Another solution to the Fermi
>   Paradox (Where Are They All?). Let's be careful about following
>   instructions from the stars.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. That's the one. Turns out it was "green scum" and not "red moss/lichen" It is indeed a highly disturbing story!

Comment: Available for [borrowing at the _Internet Archive_](https://archive.org/details/apostrophesapoca0000barn/mode/2up).

Comment: @SQB That was a good read, thanks!